# jQuery animated divs continue to move after animation is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I'm animating one circle which scales, collides with two circles nearby it, and causes those circles to be animated to a certain position. Everything works, except when those two circles are animated to their post-collision position they **continue to move**. If you run my fiddle you'll notice that afterwards the two circles which collide with the bigger circle will actually continue to inch very slowly away from the circle well after the animation is complete. I tried `.stop(true,true)` on the animate function for the middle circle, called 'boss', but that only makes it so the middle circle isn't shown to grow. I tried `.finish()` on the boss growth animation but that doesn't help the other circles which continue to inch away well after the animation is complete.

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/direlelephant/fMLKZ/2/

EDIT: This is true whether I set the position of the divs to fixed or to absolute.

EDIT: I also tried `.clearQueue()` and `.stop(true, false)` and `stop(true)`. ClearQueue() did nothing to help the problem, stop(true,false) prevented the middle circle from animating, as did stop(true).

Comment: I'm still looking at your fiddle, but it looks like your animation never stops. Inspect one of the small circles, and it looks like the `top` and `left` positioning continually update in small fractions of a pixel.

Comment: using stop like this in your animation: $(objectify3).stop().animate() stopped the loop. But this delays the start. Try to look around this.

Comment: badAdviceGuy, I thought about that too but it doesn't make that much sense to me because the for loop which defines the top and left positioning actually only executes twice, as its condition is < acollide.length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: you create animations within loop. Replace part of your code with

```
  if ( distanceformula( xcoord3, xboss, ycoord3, yboss ) < ((boss.outerWidth() / 2) + (objectify3.outerWidth() / 2)) ) {
              console.log(1)
              $( objectify3 ).animate( {
                left: xmove3 + "px",
                top: ymove3 + "px"
              }, {
                duration:3000,
                step: function() {
                  console.log(2)                  
                }
              });

            }
```

and open console.
You will see, that you created ~1000 animations (console.log(1) executes 1000 times) `$( objectify3 ).animate`, and then jQuery run 1000 animations one after one. They will end in ~1000 * 3000 seconds. 
I think you need a flag and run animations only once with first intersection.

Comment: The problem is that I can't actually detect collision unless I run that if block in the step function of the boss animate function because otherwise boss.outerWidth() will give me a constant value of 56, as opposed to a value which measures the current outerwidth of the animation.

Comment: You can check if animation running and don't run it again and again. http://jsfiddle.net/HVBpy/2/. And if it suitable you can check intersection with final bosswidth and run animations of objectify3 from the very beginning and only 1 time.